# Meaning of vorbei in this sentence

Tags: adjective, vocabulary

On the book Emil und die Detektive, by Erich Kästner, I found the following

> Da hielt die Straßenbahn zum ersten Mal. Es stieg niemand aus. Es drängten nur viele neue Fahrgäste in die Bahn. Auch an Emil vorbei. Ein Herr schimpfte, weil der Junge im Wege war.

Okay. I understood that people entered in the train pushing each other because it was crowded. So I guess the sentence *Auch an Emil vorbei* means that they also pushed Emil.

But the meaning of vorbei is "over", "finished", right? So that sentence seems very strange to me.

Can someone explain what *Auch an Emil vorbei* means there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *an … vorbei* means *passing …*. That's also the reason for the other meaning of *vorbei*. Once you have passed the obstacle, you are over it.

> Sie drängten sich **an** Emil **vorbei**.
>
> Sie **drängten** sich an Emil **vorbei**.

You may also see this as a prefixed verb *vorbeidrängen* – to push past someone/something.

Comment: You are refering of course to "Ist der Fest-Umzug hier schon vorbei?", or rather "vorbei gekommen". I'm unsure whether *vorbei* had to be prepositional or how to lex *bei*. Can we compare *probieren*, *to probe*, either, respectively, "vormachen, vorführen, examinieren", or rather "investigate" (to split of, head forwards)?

Comment: *Vorbei* isn't a preposition but an adverb. Or a prefix.

Comment: *Sie drängten sich vor Erik. Sie drängten sich vor Bayern Erik ... vorbei an Erik* meine ich natürlich. Prepositions are mostly adverbial, aren't they? How it is not an adposition is exactly my question.

Comment: You cannot say *Sie drängten sich vorbei Erik.* The word *vorbei* works just the same as *hinunter* et al.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepositional_adverb

Comment: So, «Sie drängten sich an Emil vorbei.» means something like «they pushed each other while they were passing besides Emil» ? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You will find German speakers use such adverbs a lot. Check your grammar book for *hinauf/herauf/hinunter/herunter*. They are also productive as verb prefixes.

Comment: @Janka: _an ... vorbei_ may be regarded as a *circumposition* (or a ["zirkumpositionsartige Konstruktion"](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1431) like _um ... herum_ (um die Kirche herum), _um ... willen_ (um des lieben Friedens willen), _von ... an_ (von diesem Moment an) or _an ... statt_ (an Kindes statt adoptieren).

Answer (score 2):

As we learn from the next sentence, Emil stood in the way (from the perspective of the others). Hence they had to make their push-y entrance in an even more confined space. They pushed *past* Emil